# How to catch JSON null result on Android?

Tags: android, json

I have an Android Application that invoke a REST webservice and get the JSON answer.
When I enter a wrong parameter I can catch the error without problem but sometimes some results on the JSON are null. How can I catch that situation?

My Android code:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(results);

    JSONArray result = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);

        String string04 = c.getString("string04");
        String string05 = c.getString("string05");

        TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt1.setText(string04);

        TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt2.setText(string05);


        JSONArray dest = c.getJSONArray("dest");

        for (int o = 0; o < dest.length(); o++) {

            JSONObject d = dest.getJSONObject(o);

            JSONArray pred = d.getJSONArray("pred");

            for (int u = 0; u < pred.length(); u++) {

                JSONObject e = pred.getJSONObject(u);

                String string13 = e.getString("string13");
                TextView txt4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                txt4.setText(string13);
            }
        }
    }   
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
}
```

A good JSON result would be like this:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "string01": "104",
        "string02": "104 - blablabla",
        "string03": "104",
        "string04": "blobloblo",
        "string05": "blablabla",
        "dest": [{
            "pred": [{
                "time": 1461348846,
                "sec": 102,
                "min": 1,
                "string11": "514-String",
                "string12": "Some String",
                "string13": "Some other String",
                "number": 0
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

But sometimes, when there is no data to show, I get something like this:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "string01": "104",
        "string02": "104 - blablabla",
        "string03": "104",
        "string04": "blobloblo",
        "string05": "blablabla",
        "dest": [{"pred":[]}]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Just test the length of the corresponding JSONArray object, an empty array has size 0.

Comment: The loop that goes over the `pred` array will never be entered if your list is empty, so I don't think you can get null.

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON` parser has "`opt`" methods which will return `NULL` if there's no object for the matching condition. These methods are there similar to get methods.

E.g: `getJSONObject("column")` will `throw` an `exception` if there isn't a value for "`column`"

`optJSONObject("column")` will simply return a `NULL` value if it doesn't exist. I personally find the "`opt`" methods handy when working with `JSONs` whose values might be missing at runtime.